# One PhpMyAdmin per virtualhost

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, debian, raspbian

I am relative new and learning about linux servers. I just played with them years ago.

I have configured `Apache2`, `Php5`, `MySQL`, `PhpMyAdmin`, etc. on my `Raspberry` using `Raspbian`.

I just configured some virtualhost where I am going to work, and now *I want to know if I could configure each virtualhost to have their specific phpmyadmin access and databases*.

I googled for hours but I have found nothing.

Thank you! :)

Comment: sysadmins would be in a lot better position to answer this question, since this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Thank you, just noticed stackoverflow has communities ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is available to every host via alias on addres [mysite.com/phpmyadmin](http://localhost/phpmyadmin), and if u add databases and users, then restrict users to view only certain databases, when they login, they will see only one database.
And if u want to allow phpmyadmin for certain websites remove this line

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

from

```
/etc/phpmyadmin/apache2.conf
```

and add this to vhost of site you want to enable it

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName onlyphpmyadmin.domain.com
    .
    .
    .
    Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
</VirtualHost>
```